# No space left on device when adding at.File content to site

Tags: plone

I have a content type that inherits of at.file scheme. When I try to upload a file of 2.5 gb gives me the error: no space left on device

For some reason the temp folder is filled to 100% while the object being created. The tmp folder have 10 gb.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you looked at the amount of free space on the device _before_ uploading the file, to eliminate the possibility that the full disk isn't directly related to the uploading of the file?

Comment: some linux distributions mount /tmp with tmpfs. so the temporary file get's put to RAM.
another guess would be that nginx and/or apache stores a temporary file too. you can make sure this is not the case by accessing zope directly

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why your tmp storage is full. Most other services and tools are also using the `default` TMP storage.

I usually got this problem on customer machines, if the tmp area is in its own partition and also small sized (only few hundert MBs).

Usually you can solve it by point to a other directory, for example directly in the buildout.

Python `tempfile` implementation respects the TMPDIR environment variable, so you can simply point it to another directory.

This can be done by extend the buildout configuration with:

```
[instance]
...

environment-vars +=
    TMPDIR ${buildout:directory}/tmp
....
```

Make sure you have a `tmp` directory in your buildout folder.